# Error generating chart: Remote Request too large in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I was trying to generate to spectral chart for 'VV','VH','angle' using Google Earth Engine. But I am getting the error

> Error generating chart: Remote Request too large

I was using the following code:

```
    var test1 = data
    .filterDate('2017-06-16', '2017-08-30')
    .select('VV','VH','angle')
    .filterBounds(boundary);

var stack = function(collection) 
{
  var bond = boundary
  var first = ee.Image(collection.first()).select([]);
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) 
  {

    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };  
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));
};

var stacked = stack(test1)
var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection(stacked).mosaic()
var clip = mosaic.clip(boundary)
print (stacked,'stacked')
print (clip,'clip')
var bandNames = stacked.bandNames();
print (bandNames)


Map.addLayer(clip)
print (clip,'clip')


var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: clip,
  region: paddy,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10
});


chart.style().set({
  position: 'bottom-right',
  width: '500px',
  height: '300px'
});
Map.add(chart);
```

What is wrong?

Earth Engine code link https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/82a90af6ef77a68d9e228b8aad76f17a

Comment: Does the error message really have an English error ("to large"), or was that a transcription error?

Comment: Remote request too large (608174080 > 83886080) for output:[<Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>, <Object>].

Comment: i am getting the exact error massage as above

Comment: Then [Edit] the question to reflect the exact error.

Comment: have you tried asking for a smaller image?

Comment: yes, but did helped

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `iterate()`.  Use `collection.toBands()`.  But also, it looks like you could submit the original collection to the `ui.Chart` call w/o all the mosaicking and iterating.

Comment: Hi, I did the same i.e collection.toBands() but getting the error of duplicate bands.  Image (Error)
ImageCollection.toBands: Duplicate band name: 'null_VV'.